# Bug in new reopen Q display - Chrome

Tags: bug, vote-to-reopen

Browser: Chrome Version 25.0.1364.152 m

I see when I reopen a Q now, it shows (votes/5), and when I add my vote it tries to increment to (votes+1/5) this is new, and has a bug because it doesn't replace the original but just appends to it.

[image: Bug in reopening]

```
<div class="post-menu"><a href="/q/190516/35276" title="short permalink to this question" class="short-link" id="link-post-190516">share</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a href="/posts/190516/edit" class="edit-post" title="revise and improve this post">edit</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a id="close-question-190516" title="3 more votes are needed to reopen this question" class="load-tooltip-on-hover">
            reopen
                (2/5)
         (3/5)</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a id="flag-post-190516" href="#" title="flag this post for serious problems or moderator attention">flag</a></div>
```

Comment: The bug also exists with close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been reported, confirmed, and status-completed few hours ago at Workplace meta:

Accepted answer from SE team member (Mark Gravell) says:

> Thanks; this will be fixed in the next deploy. It looks like we changed the display from `(3)` to `(3/5)`, but the javascript / regex at the client wasn't updated accordingly.

---

- Meta WP reference: [Total amount of close votes displayed twice](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/total-amount-of-close-votes-displayed-twice)

  > [image: Double Vote]